# Update Python dictionary while looping

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I was trying to iterate over a list of values, craft a dictionary to save each value in a structured way, and then append the dictionary to a new list of results, but I found an unexpected behavior.

Below is an example:

```py
values_list = [1,2,3]

# Basic dict
result_dict = {
    'my_value': ''
  }

# Iterate, craft a dictionary, and append result

dicts_list = []

for value in values_list:
  result_dict.update({'my_value': value})
  dicts_list.append(result_dict)

print(dicts_list)
```

As you can see, first I create a basic dictionary, then I'm iterating over the list of values and updating the dictionary, at the end I'm appending the crafted dictionary to a separate list of results (*dicts_list*).

As a result I was expecting:

```py
[{'my_value': 1}, {'my_value': 2}, {'my_value': 3}]
```

but instead I was getting:

```py
[{'my_value': 3}, {'my_value': 3}, {'my_value': 3}]
```

It looks like every iteration is not only updating the basic dictionary – which is expected – but also the dictionaries already appended to the list of results on the previous iteration.

To fix the issue, I nested the basic dictionary under the for loop:

```py
values_list = [1,2,3]

# Iterate, craft a dictionary, and append result

dicts_list = []

for value in values_list:
  result_dict = {'my_value': ''}
  result_dict.update({'my_value': value})
  dicts_list.append(result_dict)

print(dicts_list)
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with the first approach? How is the loop causing the list of appended dictionaries to be updated?

Thanks for any advice! :)

Franz

Comment: `dicts_list.apppend(result_dict)` doesn't make a copy of the dictionary. So all the elements of the dictionary are references to the same dictionary, which you keep updating in place.

Comment: The whole thing can just be `dicts_list = [{'my_value': value} for value in values_list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gain understanding of *How is the loop causing the list of appended dictionaries to be updated?* you can use [Python Tutor: Visualize code in Python](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display) with the code you provided in your question to see the effect of executing the code line by line with the final result being following visualization:

[image]

I suggest you read also [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, Claudio! That's exactly what I was looking for, a way to understand the code execution step by step – great resource, I'm going to use that website a lot. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, you're appending the same dictionary in each iteration because `update()` modifies the `result_dict` rather than returning a copy. So, the only change you need to do is to append a copy of the crafted dictionary. For example:

```
values_list = [1,2,3]

# Basic dict
result_dict = {
    'my_value': ''
  }

# Iterate, craft a dictionary, and append result

dicts_list = []

for value in values_list:
  result_dict.update({'my_value': value})
  dicts_list.append(dict(result_dict))  # <--- this is the only change

print(dicts_list)
```